# Latex2exp (TeX command) affects label alignment in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex2exp

A geom_boxplot that has x-axis labels with linebreaks ("\n") works great.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
theme_set(theme_grey())

set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(120), 
                 x=rep(c("bar", 
                         "long\ncategory\nname", 
                         "longspacesuperscript\n(mm$^{2}$)"
                          ), 
                       each=40)
                  )

#Normal boxplot labels with line breaks
p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  ggtitle("No latex2exp (TeX command) used line breaks in x axis labels work, alignment ok")

print(p1)
```

[image: p1 correct alignment and line breaks]

```
#Boxplot labels using TeX
p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + 
     geom_boxplot() +
     scale_x_discrete(labels = latex2exp::TeX) +
     ggtitle("Latex2exp (TeX command) affect label alignment??")


print(p2)
```

[image: p2 labels are left aligned and superscript is filled out?]

```
# We can change the position of the labels in the plot, 
# but not within the textbox that the label seems to be nested in?
p3 <- p2 + theme_set(theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=-1))) +
        ggtitle("Latex2exp (TeX command) label position adjusted")
print(p3)
```

[image: Latex2exp (TeX command) label position adjustnment (vjust=-1, hjust = 0.5) works but not within the TeXbox??]

Latex alignment commands in TeX() didnt work \centre \raggedleft etc.

Question(s): How can you change the alignment within the latex2exp::TeX() environment?
Does that work in ggplot labels ? (without manually adding the label text,
i.e. using default label names based on data (factor) naming, as I sort of did in the example)?

Or maybe a complete work around to have expected behavior and still used LaTeX within ggplot?

[image]
Based on comment of shafee I added this expected plot with center alignment and no overriding of the bottom x (similar as first plot but with correct LaTeX interpretation)

Comment: Is the 3rd plot your expected plot? I mean it seems to work in the 3rd one, right?

Comment: I have added a 4th plot to show the difference and clarify what goes wrong in my opinion. All labels are suddenly left aligned and the superscripts stretches' (see thirdbox bracket closing and white space) due to TeX usage.

Comment: Ok thanks. But must the solution use latex2exp? or also other workaround would work for you that gets the expected plot?

Comment: There's a possible way (and actually easier than writing latex expression and data frame oriented) to get that expected plot using `ggplot2` but not using latex expression and `latex2exp` package.

Comment: Please tell me. I use latex2exp mainly for math symbols, sub and superscript. So if this is possible with another package or ggplot2 itself let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain that plot using html or markdown math expression along with functions from `ggtext` package.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(
    y = rnorm(120),
    x = rep(
        c(
            "bar",
            "long<br>category<br>name",
            "longspacesuperscript<br>(mm<sup>2</sup>)"
        ),
        each = 40
    )
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    ggtitle("This works using html expression with ggtext package") +
    theme(
        axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown()
    )
```

[image: a plot with latexlike expression in axis label]

Comment: Great and for math symbols ggtext understands this syntax: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/symbol.html   (Character entity) e.g. &alpha; or &Pi; Thanks, I will be using this a lot !

Comment: Yes, you can do a lot, in this method and I think its easier and flexible than using latex expression